# send on post only files that are not empty

Tags: javascript, html, file, send

I have three input file on a form:

```
<td><input type="file" name="image_url1"/></td>
<td><input type="file" name="image_url2"/></td>
<td><input type="file" name="image_url3"/></td>
```

I want to send (on post) only files that we selected (input files that stay empty => don't send them).

How can i do that?

Comment: You would have to manually make the request and pass only the items you want, either via an Ajax call or some other technology. Why can you not just manually handle empty items on the Server side?

Comment: You should still handle this server side and not depend on the client to make sure that the files are not empty.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.length` to check file length, and disable empty controls. This way they will not be posted.

```
 $('input[type=file]').each(function () {
        if (this.value == "" || this.files.length == 0) {
            this.prop('disabled', true)
        }

    });
```

**UPDATE:**
If you are not using jQuery, you can do this by simple javascript as:

```
var myFiles = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=file]");
for(var i = 0; i<myFiles.length; i++)
{
   if(myFiles[i].value == "" || myFiles[i].files.length == 0)
   {
      myFiles[i].disabled = true;
   }  
}
```